# android - RadioButton and RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button

is there any way by which i can save the checked state of the radiobutton whose effect remains even after i have call radiogroupinstance.clearCheck()

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store which state has been checked in a variable. Other wise the state would be lost IMO. After clearing you can set the checked state again using RadioGroup.check(int id)